# Integrating over a parallelogram without using a Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Parallelogram R has vertices $(4,-1), (6,3), (2,7),$ and $(0,3)$. Compute $\iint_R3xdA$ without using a Jacobian.

[image]

I'm having difficulty figuring this out. Is it possible for me to use vectors to integrate this? I know that I have to use multiple integrals, but I don't know where to begin. I believe $R_1=R_2$, which is all I have to go on so far.

Comment: If you wish to do this without using Jacobians, you can do this as three double integrals. You already have the lines that forms the parallelogram, so just rearrange the equations and have dA as dYdX.

Comment: @FyendFyre So if I have three double integrals would two of them be the same?

Comment: no. you will have one for each of the regions as shown in the picture. the bounds for x and y will be different for each one.